# Replace all double square brackets with custom input tags in angular or java script

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working in an angular project and I have a string like this

`var x = "Hello, [[this]] {{is}} {Mike} [example]. Replace [[this too]]";`

I want to replace all the double square brackets with custom input tags which have the word as value

Expected output:

`Hello, <input type="text" value="this"> {{is}} {Mike} [example]. Replace <input type="text" value="this too">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a while loop that uses [substrings](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) and [indexOfs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp). It makes use of the often neglected second parameter for `indexOf`, which allows you to specify the minimum starting position for the search.

```js
var str = "Hello, [[this]] {{is}} {Mike} [example]. Replace [[this too]]";
while(str.indexOf("[[") > -1 && str.indexOf("]]", str.indexOf("[[") + 2) > -1){
 str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("[[")) + "<input type=\"text\" value=\"" + str.substring(str.indexOf("[[") + 2, str.indexOf("]]", str.indexOf("[[") + 2)) + "\"/>" + str.substring(str.indexOf("]]", str.indexOf("[[") + 2) + 2);
}

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go... You can replace them with **Regular Expression**.

```js
var x = "Hello, [[this]] {{is}} {Mike} [example]. Replace [[this too]]";

console.log(x.replace(/]]/g,'"\/>').replace(/\[\[/g,'<input type="text" value="'));
```

Comment: Is it possible to make click function in the input using angular? I am facing the issues in inner html. Please guide me how to make some events like click or drag in the particular HTML Tag only

Comment: Just do ```document.querySelector(/* selector of your element */).click()```.